# File list combined with excluded mimeType in query and maxResults returns incorrect amount

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to grab the five most recently edited items, which works fine using the code:

```
files = service.files().list(maxResults=5).execute()

Folder1
Document1
Document2
Folder2
Document3
```

But when I try to exclude folders, the amount returned is incorrectly including the folders in the maxResults count:

```
files = service.files().list(q="mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'", maxResults=5).execute()

Document1
Document2
Document3
```

There are hundreds of files in my Drive so it isn't a result of there only being 3 documents.

Are there any workarounds to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report. Google reproduced the same result and is investigating on this case.